# How to get this output "Output- Mon-Wed-7-19 Thu-11-19 Friday -Sat open 24 hours Sun-closed" from this input

Tags: python, list

Input 1: opening hrs = [7 , 7, 7, 11, 15, 10, 17]
closing hrs = [19, 19, 19, 19, 15, 10, 7] given this input. I have tried couple ways one such is below. Even this solution is not correct.
Solution which I have tried from my end,

```
opening_hrs = [7 , 7, 7, 11, 15, 17, 17]
closing_hrs = [19, 19, 19, 19, 15, 7, 7]
days = ['Mon', 'Tue', 'W', 'Th', 'Fr', 'Sa', 'Su']
tmp = [timings[0]]
out = days[0]
for every in range(len(timings)):
    if timings[every] not in tmp:
        out += '-' + days[every-1]

        out += str(timings[every-1]) + '\n'
        if every != len(timings) -1:
            tmp.append(timings[every])
else:
    if timings[-1] not in tmp:
        out += '-' + days[-1]

        out += str(timings[-1]) + '\n'
        tmp.append(timings[-1])
print(out)
```

I was able to map things and return out for all the days like from Monday to Sunday and their corresponding timings, but couldn't return the output such that if the timings are same for the consecutive days then we should combine those days and show the one timing for them like (Mon -Wed -- 7 to 19).

Comment: how do you manage your output according to the inputs ?

Comment: Generally, on Stackoverflow, you should try first yourself, and ask for help with problems. It's not a site to get other people to do your homework for you.

Comment: @LennartRegebro, sorry my bad. Actually this is my first time of asking for a help in stackoverflow. So I didn't do it in a correct way, but I was not asking someone else to solve my homework. I have tried for many hours and searched at many places in the google and then finally I decided to seek some help from stackoverflow. Yeah I did not post what I have tried, my mistake, but my intention was not what you have mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Use zip() to combine day names with opening and closing times.
Then merge consecutive days that have the same hours (starting from the end of the week going backward to allow deleting items from the list within the for loop):

```
openTime  = [7 , 7, 7, 11, 15, 10, 17]
closeTime = [19, 19, 19, 19, 15, 10, 7]
days      = ['Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday',
             'Saturday','Sunday']

hours     = [[d,f"{ot}-{ct}" if ot<ct else "24 hours" if ct==ot else "closed"] 
             for d,ot,ct in zip(days,openTime,closeTime)]

for i,(day,time) in enumerate(hours[:0:-1]):      # backwards through days
    if time==hours[5-i][-1]:                      # same times as previous
        hours[5-i][0] += "-" + day.split("-")[-1] # merge into previous
        del hours[6-i]                            # remove merged day entry

        
print(", ".join(f"{days}:{time}" for days,time in hours))

Monday-Wednesday:7-19, Thursday:11-19, Friday-Saturday:24 hours, Sunday:closed
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @alain T. I was able to reach till the point of mapping, but my brain didn't get any thoughts about last part of putting the days together if the timings is same. Your way of approach is too good. How did this idea strike your mind? is there any algorithm which you used here?

Comment: I simplified the code a bit, perhaps it'll make it easier to understand.

Comment: Alain T, I got your previous solution as well. It was very clear and I understood this solution as well. I was asking you how that idea of iterating from last and if the time is same you merge those days, right, how this idea strike your mind. Any sort algorithms that helped you to get this? So I was asking you indirectly which background work helped you to get this solution.

Comment: Hard to say where I got that from, it just seemed obvious. I've been programming for 45 years so I don't really remember when or how I got the stuff in my bag of tricks.  The only thing I can recommend is to practice, and, if you like puzzles, try to find solutions to questions on stack overflow.  You'll learn a lot comparing your solutions to other people's. (I know I'm still learning stuff doing that)